# UTC Timestamp in milliseconds to short datetime string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timestamp, utc

How can I convert a UTC [timestamp](http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/ref/Types.html#Typedef_Timestamp) in milliseconds to a short date time in c#?

Comment: sorry I meant timestamp like this http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/ref/Types.html#Typedef_Timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DateTime UnixStartDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
YourDate = UnixStartDate.AddMilliseconds(YourTimestamp).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Don't forget the .ToShortDateString() at the end of the second line :)